# writing to a json file from python

Tags: python, json, editing

how do i edit/change a particular field in a json file using python code:

```
{
   "EZMessage":{
      "action":"account.cash",
      "data":{
         "authToken":"123456",
         "account":"#ACCOUNTID#",
         "portfolio":"true",
         "historical":"true"
      }
   }
}
```

in this json code, i want to replace 123456 with 789123

string replace only works if i know what is written there. in my code, i would only know what to write, and the identifier "authToken". Is there a way to overwrite the 123456 by identifying that it is the value of "authToken" ?

thanks,

RS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module to convert the string to a set of nested `dict` objects, make your changes, and then dump the dictionary back to a json string.

```
import json
jstr = '''{
   "EZMessage":{
      "action":"account.cash",
      "data":{
         "authToken":"123456",
         "account":"#ACCOUNTID#",
         "portfolio":"true",
         "historical":"true"
      }
   }
}'''

j = json.loads(jstr)
j['EZMessage']['data']['authToken'] = 654321
jstr = json.dumps(j)
```

For how to read-from/write-to a file see [the fine tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: thanks - actually this is a json file (TXT.json) and i have to write the modified json in there. how do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Convert the JSON object to a Python object, then change the value just like any other Python object.

Comment: I guess i am looking for a function that helps me write into a json file (TXT.json) into a specific field like: ['EZMessage']['data']['authToken']